# How can I split out an 'any' variable in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to get multiple values out of an 'any' type variable. I'm new to terraform and open to recommendations. Specifically for this example, I'd like to know how I can output the 'bucket_name' value in my outputs.

```
variable "replica_config" {
  type = any
  default = {
    role = "role_name"
    rules = [
      {
        id                        = "full-s3-replication"
        status                    = true
        priority                  = 10
        delete_marker_replication = false
        destination = {
          bucket             = "bucket_name"
          storage_class      = "STANDARD"
          replica_kms_key_id = "key_id"
          account_id         = "account_id"
          replication_time = {
            status  = "Enabled"
            minutes = 15
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Current Output:

```
output "output4" {
  value = flatten(var.replica_config["rules"])
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Any errors? What exactly is the outcome of the `output4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you you have a list for `rules`, you can use a [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) as such:

```
output "output4" {
  value = var.replica_config.rules[*].destination.bucket
}
```

Keep in mind, the output of this expression will also be a list. If you want a single item instead of a list, you can use an index.

For example:

```
output "output4" {
  value = var.replica_config.rules[0].destination.bucket
}
```